# Populating large matrix with equation in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, vector

I am trying to populate a matrix using two for loops. The inner loop is supposed to calculate one row (points in space) and the outer loop is supposed to calculate the next point in time for each of those points in space. I'm not sure how to fill the blank matrix I made initially with each new calculated row. Here is my code:

```
L=100           #[m]
S=0.01
n=0.0036        #[s/m^1/3]
train=720       #[s]
qrain=0.0000027 #[m/s]
t=3600          #[s]
dx=10           #[m]
dt=0.01         #[s]
N=1/dt

h=matrix(,nrow=N*t,ncol=10)

h[1,]=0

for (j in 1:nrow(h)) {
    if(j<(train/dt)) q=qrain
    else q=0

    for (i in 1:ncol(h)) {

        h[i,j+1]=h[i,j]-(dt*S/n)*((h[(i+1),j]^(5/3)-h[i,j]^(5/3))/dx)+q

    }

    v=matrix(((S^0.5)/n)*(h^(2/3)),nrow=nrow(h),ncol=ncol(h))
}

q=matrix(v*h,nrow=nrow(h),ncol=ncol(h))
```

Is it valid to write my equation this way? I also want the whole first row h[1,] to be zeros, and it only wants to make h[1,1] a 0. Not sure if I'm missing something obvious. Thanks in advance for the help! (It's my first post here).

Comment: I would say this is valid and the first row `h[1, ] = 0`. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Thanks. h[1,]=0 still doesn't fill the whole first row with zeros, just the first cell, for some reason. And I'm still having trouble writing to the matrix. Should I create the matrix as I go through the loop (rbind) instead of making it up front?

Comment: `h[1,0]=0` *does* set the whole row to 0. Use `head(h)` right after the assignment statement to see this. You are setting the other columns of row 1 to `NA` in your loop. Also, did you run this code? You inner loop runs for `i=1:ncol(h)`, but you reference col `i+1` in the loop, so eventually you get an error. Same problem referencing row `j+1` and having `j=1:nrow(h)`.

Comment: You're right about the first row. I think I see the problem with the loops, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Do you think I should make the loops run `for (j in 1:(nrow(h)-1)) {`and `for (i in 1:(ncol(h)-1)) {`? I get the error `Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, j + 1, value = NA_real_) :  subscript out of bounds`. But I've gotten that error before. It did spend more time trying to run this time, but still gave me a row of zeros and a bunch of NAs. Thanks for the help.